# Webfrom Validation on textfiled when using default value

Tags: webforms, forms

I am having a problem where I need to use the default value of a text field to initially populate the from visually. Unfortunately after doing this the field validates as if it has been filled out by a user.
I am attempting to do a custom validation function to check against the default value of the field. So if the field has its default value to still validate as a mandatory field normally would.

The following is my attempt to do this. Am I going in the right direction?

```
    function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_6'){
       //kpr($form);    
        $form['#validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_validate_form';
    }
```

}

```
function MY_MODULE_validate_form($form,&$form_state){
if ($form_state['submitted']['full_name']['#default_value'] == "Full Name") {
    form_set_error('full_name', t('You Must enter your full name'));
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that this isnt a direct answer to your question, but it seems to me to be bad practice to use a default value in an input field and then disregard it as a submission. Would a placeholder not  be more appropriate for your requirements? 
You could even style the placeholder to look like form input via CSS

Comment: but if you really intent on doing it as you described in your question your $form_state variable looks a bit suspect. try something like if($form_state['values']['full_name'] == "Full Name") instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Yes that sounds like the proper solution. How is the best practice to set placeholders?

Comment: you want the form input to look something like this <input type = "text" name = "full_name" placeholder = "Full Name"> You can add a place holder in a Drupal form by adding it as an attribute of the field, so for the above input in your element declaration have '#attributes' => array('Placeholder' => 'Full Name'),

Comment: You are very much welcome :)